# Problema al deserializar JSON en dataSet

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, dataset

Estoy tratando de deserializar un resultado JSON hacia un `dataset`. Al tratar de hacerlo me arroja el siguiente error:

> Additional text found in JSON string after finishing deserializing object. Path `'[0].studentID'`, line 1,

No veo que texto adicional pueda estar obteniendo desde el JSON

Estos son los datos del JSON

```
[
    {
        "studentID": "student123@test.org",
        "facultyID": "faculty123@test.org",
    }
]
```

Esta es la clase creada

```
[Serializable]
class Parameters
{
     public string studentID { get; set; }
     public string facultyID { get; set; }
}
```

Este es parte de mi codigo

```
IList<Parameters> searchResultsFromJason = new List<Parameters>();

string resultJSonRequest = "";

using (HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)

using (var reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
{
    var result = reader.ReadToEnd();

    string resultWebService = Convert.ToString(result);

    var JasonResultList = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(resultWebService.ToString());

    resultJSonRequest = resultWebService;

    IList<JToken> results = JasonResultList.ToList();

    IList<Parameters> searchResults = new List<Parameters>();

    searchResultsFromJason = searchResults;

    foreach (JToken resultJAson in results)
    {
        Parameters searchResult = resultJAson.ToObject<Parameters>();
        searchResults.Add(searchResult);

    }
}
```

Es aqui donde se cae el codigo y me aroja el error `'Additional text found in JSON string after finishing deserializing object. Path '[0].studentID', line 1,'`

```
DataSet dataSet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(resultJSonRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Un DataSet es una representación de una base de datos, es decir puede contener muchas tablas, a tu json de origen le falta indicar a que tabla pertenece ese arreglo, es decir tu json debería ser algo así.

```
{
    "parameters": [
        {
            "studentID": "student123@test.org",
            "facultyID": "faculty123@test.org"      
        }
    ]
}
```

UPDATE:

Si forzosamente lo necesitas en DataSet deberás agregarle la parte que le falta, pero puedes traerlo directamente al objeto destino.

```
List<Parameters> parametros = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Parameters>>(resultJSonRequest);
```

Comment: Pero mi problema que el json no tiene un parametro como ese, solo me envian el que puse en mi ejemplo. Sabes de que forma podria referenciarlo igual?

Comment: Si forzosamente necesitas convertirlo a DataSet al que te llega agregale esa parte que le falta, de lo contrario puedes convertirlo directamente a un objeto (Clase)

Comment: Si necesito forzosamente convertirlo en dataset. Cuando mencionas que puedo agregarle esa parte que le fatla. Como puedo hacerlo?

Comment: si no quieres usar dataset, te recomiendo hacer tracking en modo debug de los datos que te devuelve tu consulta sql  en las reglas de negocio de tu codigo c#

Comment: Ok, vi el codigo adicional que me mencionas, pero eso debo hacerlo antes de la linea del dataset?

Comment: Y no es más fácil deserializarlo en objetos y luego esos objetos pasarlos a dataset? Digo, es la idea del json, no veo porqué complicarse tanto.